# Can one work for his own startup while working in some other company with a bond?

Tags: india, startup, employment-bond

My friend wants to establish a startup. He is currently working in a startup company with two year bond. Simply he wants to know whether it is ethical to work for his startup while working for the company or should he leave the company by paying the bond amount.

Comment: read the contract

Comment: Where is this (country, province, state)? Employment law varies a lot.

Comment: If your friend's startup is in the same industry as the one he is working for, it may constitute a conflict of interest.

Comment: What is a 'bond'?

Comment: Tagged as [tag:india], as that's the location given on OP's profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your friend should read the contract he signed with the startup he's currently working for.

In most jurisdictions, it is legal to have two jobs, but he may be covered by specific laws, or may have agreed not to.

Comment: "It's perfectly legal to have two jobs" - this may not be true for every country or state. For what it's worth, OP appears to be in India.

Comment: @Dukeling: Yes. I edited to mention that there _may_ be laws forbidding two jobs.